# splitpanes: achieve synchronized scrolling and fixed/sticky header

Tags: css, vuejs2

Sandbox.vue

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid>
    <Splitpanes
      class="default-theme"
      style="height: 400px"
    >
      <Pane
        v-for="i in 2"
        :key="i"
      >
        <div class="pa-4">
          <div>Header</div>
          <div>
            <!-- very long text... -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </Pane>
    </Splitpanes>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import { Splitpanes, Pane } from 'splitpanes'
import 'splitpanes/dist/splitpanes.css'

export default {
  components: {
    Splitpanes,
    Pane
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.splitpanes__pane {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
</style>
```

[image]

I'd like to have a synchronized scrolling (scrolling both left and right, like when comparing code) and a sticky/fixed header. How can I achieve this result?

**Edit #1**

I achieved synchronized scrolling this way:

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-card
      class="overflow-y-auto"
      height="400"
      outlined
      flat
    >
      <Splitpanes
        class="default-theme"
        style="height: auto"
      >
        <Pane min-size="1">
          <div class="sticky">
            Header
          </div>
          <div class="pa-4">
            <!-- Very long text... -->
          </div>
        </Pane>
        <Pane min-size="1">
          <div class="sticky">
            Header
          </div>
          <div class="pa-4">
            <!-- Very long text... -->
          </div>
        </Pane>
      </Splitpanes>
    </v-card>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import { Splitpanes, Pane } from 'splitpanes'
import 'splitpanes/dist/splitpanes.css'

export default {
  components: {
    Splitpanes,
    Pane
  }
}
</script>

<style>
.splitpanes.default-theme .splitpanes__pane {
  background: transparent;
}
.default-theme.splitpanes--vertical > .splitpanes__splitter {
  border-left: none;
}
.default-theme.splitpanes--vertical > .splitpanes__splitter::before,
.default-theme.splitpanes--vertical > .splitpanes__splitter::after {
  height: 100%;
}
.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
</style>
```

About the fixed/sticky header, I created the sticky class, but it doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know how to achieve this result?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the projects available here: https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#scroll
It looks like [vue-scroll-sync](https://github.com/metawin-m/vue-scroll-sync) is doing just that.

---

UPDATE: after trying some time I didn't achieved to make it work properly...

This is how far I went without any success

```html
<template>
  <div style="display: flex">
    <scroll-sync :vertical="true">
      <div
        style="width: 100px; height: 600px; overflow: auto; background: teal"
      >
        Nam id faucibus turpis. Sed in ex gravida lorem tincidunt posuere. Cras
        id velit ac diam pretium cursus. Aliquam sagittis magna non ante
        vehicula, ac venenatis leo consequat. Fusce blandit, enim sit amet
        scelerisque lobortis, neque ex cursus velit, sed sodales urna nibh
        tempor urna. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam sit amet arcu at mauris
        fringilla accumsan sit amet ac mi. Mauris consectetur est ligula, eu
        tristique nibh sollicitudin in. Sed malesuada neque ut ante ultrices
        malesuada. Curabitur imperdiet neque quis est sodales, id pellentesque
        nibh eleifend. Maecenas cursus, nibh vitae congue accumsan, nisl lectus
        pharetra dolor, a ornare diam purus at metus. Vestibulum porta, quam
        eget venenatis hendrerit, massa tortor faucibus arcu, ac pellentesque
        felis mi et quam. Etiam sollicitudin pretium diam, at fringilla velit
        gravida ut. Vestibulum a felis at sapien rutrum fringilla. Donec eu
        viverra enim. Etiam consectetur elit non nibh ornare blandit. Curabitur
        ultrices ante quis ipsum efficitur sodales. Sed porttitor lorem vitae
        ipsum volutpat eleifend. Cras libero nisl, porta sit amet maximus ac,
        finibus id risus.
      </div>
    </scroll-sync>
    <scroll-sync :vertical="true">
      <div style="width: 100px; height: 300px; overflow: auto; background: red">
        Nam id faucibus turpis. Sed in ex gravida lorem tincidunt posuere. Cras
        id velit ac diam pretium cursus. Aliquam sagittis magna non ante
        vehicula, ac venenatis leo consequat. Fusce blandit, enim sit amet s
        nibh eleifend. Maecenas cursus, nibh vitae congue accumsan, nisl lectus
        pharetra dolor, a ornare diam purus at metus. Vestibulum porta, quam
        eget venenatis hendrerit, massa tortor faucibus arcu, ac pellentesque
        felis mi et quam. Etiam sollicitudin pretium diam, at fringilla velit
        gravida ut. Vestibulum a felis at sapien rutrum fringilla. Donec eu
        viverra enim. Etiam consectetur elit non nibh ornare blandit. Curabitur
        ultrices ante quis ipsum efficitur sodales. Sed porttitor lorem vitae
        ipsum volutpat eleifend. Cras libero nisl, porta sit amet maximus ac,
        finibus id risus.
      </div>
    </scroll-sync>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  components: {
    [process.client && 'ScrollSync']: () => import('vue-scroll-sync'),
  },
}
</script>
```

Since the maintainer does not really have any more details, I'm not sure how to contact him better.

---

TLDR: I guess that somebody would need to implement that one by hand unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. It might be that splitpanes component is not the proper one. If you have any suggestions, you're welcome.

Comment: @PyKKe I'm not using `splitpanes` in my example. But I couldn't achieve more neither haha.

Comment: I managed to get the synchronized scrolling, now I only need to implement the fixed/sticky header.